# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir

Tags: discord.js

I updated my code to v13 today and now when i try to start my discord bot i'm getting an error, but when i go back to v12 this error is not anymore here..
https://pastebin.com/9puJMkSQ
This is my code

```
 constructor(guild) {
        this.guild = guild;

        const storagePath = "./root/DiscordMusicGiveawayBotNew/storage/"
        if (!fs.existsSync(storagePath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(storagePath);
        }

        const myStorage = "./root/DiscordMusicGiveawayBotNew/storage/" + this.guild.name;
        if (!fs.existsSync(myStorage)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(myStorage);
        }

        const dirPath = './root/DiscordMusicGiveawayBotNew/storage/' + this.guild.name + "/giveaways";

        if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
        }

        const dir = fs.opendirSync(dirPath);
```

What's wrong with it? It work perfectly in v12, but when i change to v13 it return an error that prevent us to start our code

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to pass the `recursive: true` option. I don't think this is related to NodeJS version tho.

`fs.mkdirSync(storagePath, { recursive: true })`

Comment: I tried, but it give me another error : /root/DiscordMusicGiveawayBotNew/guildStorage.js:68
            fs.mkdirSync(myStorage,{recursive:true});
                         ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'myStorage' before initialization

Comment: that's JS syntax error. Don't use variables before initializing them